# Notification Timing Issue

Tags: java, android, push

I need the code of Android notification with timing when notification was received.

I was testing notification in my app with following code

```
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    Log.d("App Loaded ==", "Do");

    NotificationManager notif=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notify=new Notification.Builder
      (getApplicationContext()).setContentTitle("testing").setContentText("This is testing").
      setContentTitle("time notification").setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification).build();

    notify.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notif.notify(0, notify);
}
```

Kindly suggest why this is not working on page finished event. No notification is being triggered.

Comment: Which Android version are you testing on? Starting with Oreo, you need channels for your `Notification`s.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check **android version** from where you are testing the app.

if its **Oreo+** then you have to add notification channel, otherwise you will not get notification.

and please replace the Notification class with NotificationCompat as its deprecated.

**try with this code you will surely get notification.**

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(id, name, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
            notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
            notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});

            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx, id)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(artist)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setCustomContentView(contentView)
                .setColor(ctx.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary))
                .setDefaults(DEFAULT_SOUND | DEFAULT_VIBRATE);


        if (notificationManager != null) {
            notification =builder.build();
            notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());
        }
```

and if you want to log time while notification coming, you can add 1 line of code inside the Onreceived : `Log.d(TAG, "Time: "+System.currentTimeMillis());`